# Optimise a heavy response on the client side

Tags: optimization, frontend, client

"What would you do in order to optimise a request with a heavyweight response of 10mb only on client side?"

I would like to state that this question was available on glassdoor.
It got me interested in knowing the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know from where you found this question:), anyway below is the answer of your question(as per my understanding).
If you are getting heaving data from backend then first you need to improve your code at backend side so that you will get the data is lesser time, If you can't improve the code/performance at backend side then you can use any of the below technique at frontend side -

1. Make your application PWA(Progressive Web Application): Here the person(Interviewer) specifically wanted to know whether you have understanding about PWA or not, now a days people are making their application PWA, so that they can increase the load time of their application, reuse the same code/files like common css & js files, common images etc in their application and people can access their application in slow bandwidth as well.
2. Use Lazy Loading: When user required the data then load it only (For example Medium websites you can check)
3. Minification your application
4. Use Hex code icons or Fontawesome rather then to use images for icons also you can use image compressor plugin as well

Comment: first of all thank you for your answer. I got this question from Glassdoor but I forgot which company I was checking their questions :D. Now regarding your 1st suggestion about PWAs, I don't see exactly how they help in this scenario. I was thinking if it is possible to have the data being processed while being downloaded. Like for example if you process each 500 KB but I expect that to be done in different protocol than the usual HTTP protocol @GreatKT